# RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have this code, and I keep getting this error:

```
RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.

    at Object.run (C:\Users\Sochum\Desktop\BobloxBot\commands\GroupStats.js:41:2)

Line 41 has this code: .addFields(
```

Here is the code:

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
.setTitle(`${groupname}`)
.addFields(     
    { name: ` Group Owner`, value:  `<@${owner}>` },

    { name: ` Group Co-Owner`, value:  `<@${co_owner}>` },
    { name: ` Member Count`, value:  `${membercount}` },
    { name: ` Group Funds`, value:  `${funds}` },
    { name: ` Group Items`, value:  `${group_items}` },
    { name: `Group Birthday`, value:  `${Group_Bday}` },
    { name: `Group Sharing Circle`, value:  `${sharing_circle}` },
    { name: `Group Warwins`, value:  `${Group_Warwins}` },
    { name: `Group Warlosses`, value:  `${Group_Warlosses}` },
  )   
  message.channel.send(embed)
```

I can't seem to find a problem anywhere, so I am not sure why I am getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran your code and it works fine for me. This error happens when one of the field value is empty, so be sure that all your variables are defined and that they can be read inside of a string.